# Is it possible to generate IPA file for free?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa

is it possible to generate IPA file for free, without paying 100$ to apple ?
I mean, only with the free Apple Id, and without the premium developer account.
If yes, then how? I have virtual mac, which has Xcode on it, and I cant build and archive the project because it says that I need to have provisioning profile.
Please help me. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no way to install software on iOS other than through the App Store, you pretty much have to have the account to distribute iOS software.

Comment: I can't send to my email an IPA file, and then open it on my iphone ?

Comment: iOS doesn't have sideloading, so no.

Comment: Oh, okay. Can I plug my iphone to my computer via USB, and run the application in the Xcode on my iphone, and then I will have it on my iphone ?

Comment: Otherwise, how could I check my application on a real device, before uploading to the app store ?

Comment: You can do it using Xcode, but you have to have an Apple account. Googling it, I did find this website which claims it might actually work with the free Apple ID, although I've never tried it. May be worth a try though: http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/12/howto-sideload-apps-iphone-ipad-xcode/

Comment: Thank you very much. So you are saying that there is no way without USB ?

Comment: Not as far as I know. And without the paid account, you won't be able to distribute your app to anyone, since they can only get it through the App Store. So it's best just to pony up for the account.

Comment: Also, understand that the free developer account will install the app on your device with a 7-day expiration.  So you'll have to build a new version every week or so.  When you app appears to crash on launch, likely it is the provisioning profile expiring.